# Inserting two rows from single row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql, insert

I have to import users from the `usersToImport` table into the `userContact` table. `usersToImport` contains telephone and e-mail information in a single row for each user, but `userContact` stores one kind of contact information per row.

Here's how I'm doing it currently: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c9b2e/1 (for some reason, it's not outputting anything, but the code works in SSMS).

Is there a way to do this without using two different selects? Maybe self-joining `usersToImport` or using `case` somehow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Aaron mentioned, for some reason you need to terminate each statement in Fiddle.

Anyway, for the query, you can use `CROSS APPLY` to expand the result set. This method scans the base table only once, and for each row applies the subquery, which in this case actually selects *two* rows:

```
INSERT INTO userContact(userId, contactType, contactInfo)
  SELECT
    ui.userId,
    c.contactType,
    c.contactInfo
    FROM usersToImport ui
    CROSS APPLY
    (
      SELECT 'email' AS contactType, ui.email AS contactInfo UNION ALL
      SELECT 'telephone', ui.telephone
    ) c;
```

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot! I've never used cross apply because I didn't understand how it could be useful (or how it differs from a join), but this is a great example.

Comment: @Dang: `CROSS APPLY` is like a join, except you can use correlated parameters from the outer query. The drawback is that this construct usually generates a Nested Loops plan, which can be wildly inappropriate if you're not careful. It's okay here because the subquery resolves to a constant scan (i.e., it doesn't do any real data access).

Comment: @JonSeigel Isn't it the same as a `cross join`, though?

Comment: @Dang: None of the `JOIN`s allow correlated parameters. In this particular case, `CROSS APPLY` does *act* a bit like a `CROSS JOIN` in that it expands the result set, but no, it's not the same thing at all in general.

Answer (score 3):

A few other ways to do it, no real difference in performance even when I scaled up to 1 million rows:

```
INSERT userContact ( userId, contactType, contactInfo )
SELECT u.userId, x.contactType, x.contactInfo
FROM usersToImport u
    CROSS APPLY (
        VALUES 
        ( 'email', email ),
        ( 'telephone', telephone )
    ) x ( contactType, contactInfo )


INSERT userContact ( userId, contactType, contactInfo )
SELECT userId, contactType, contactInfo
FROM 
    ( 
    SELECT userId, email, CAST( telephone AS VARCHAR(200) ) telephone 
    FROM usersToImport 
    ) u
UNPIVOT ( contactInfo FOR contactType In ([email], [telephone]) ) upvt
```

Comment: I like the way you used `values` here, thanks! =]

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your code, you just [forgot to use semi-colons to terminate your statements](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons).

[The following works just fine](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c9b2e/8):

```
insert userContact
select userId,
    'email',
    email
from usersToImport
union all
select userId,
    'telephone',
    telephone
from usersToImport;
------------------^

select * from usersToImport;
---------------------------^

select * from userContact;
-------------------------^
```

And to be quite honest, I don't think you'll find a more efficient way to turn 5 rows into 10.

Comment: I thought there might have been a more efficient way. Since there isn't, I guess this is it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Dang there may be, but I can't think of one off the top of my head. Most other approaches will scan the table twice, even if the query doesn't look like it will...

Comment: I just realized the insert was not being executed correctly in SQL Fiddle because it was lacking a semi-colon. I wish they'd say something about that when you tried running the query.